# Storing AngularJS model initial state

Tags: angularjs

I have repository factory in my application:

```
 angular.module().factory('userRepository', function(){
    return {
            getById: function(id){},
            getAll: function(){},
            delete: function(id) {},
    };
});
```

In my view i need to create a new User entity with some predefined state. which i'll modify with UI and will save with repository.

Where should i store this predefined value? in controller, in constant/value()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a factory method:

```
angular.module('app').factory('userRepository', function(){
    return {
        createUser:function() {
            return {
               name:'',
               email: ''
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Usage:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, userRepository) {
     $scope.user = userRepository.createUser();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite personal opition based, but I would create a method `createNew()` on the repository so the data related operationd with `user` are there on one place.

```
 angular.module().factory('userRepository', function(){
    return {
            createNew: function() { return ... }
            getById: function(id){},
            getAll: function(){},
            delete: function(id) {},
    };
});
```

Comment: the problem semantically this means you are creating a new entity in a DB

Comment: Agreed. To keep it purely clean you could have another layer of services - then e.g. `userService` which would hide the interaction with repositories. I can imagine that in future the initial value for `user` would have to include some db operations too (e.g. get default statusId), for that the `userService` suite the best too.

Answer (score 0):

For my small project i decided to keep all logically related entities in single place, but to keep it intuitive. So i created 2 factories: for repository, and for entity:

```
angular.module().factory('userRepository', function(){
return {
        getById: function(id){},
        getAll: function(){},
        delete: function(id) {},
    };
})
.factory('userDefinitionRepository', function(){
    return {
        newUser: function{ ... }
    };
});
```